# Get the youngest worker's name of workers who have joined multiple projects

Tags: sql, join, subquery

There are two tables that are relevant. **Workers** and **Project_workers**. Table **Workers** has worker_id, worker_name, birthdate and table **Project_workers** has project_id, worker_id.
The SQL that I have written is:

```
select worker_name, b.worker_id
from workers as a
inner join project_worker as b
on a.worker_id=b.worker_id
where b.worker_id in
(select b.worker_id
from project_worker
group by b.worker_id
having count(distinct project_id) > 1)
order by birthdate desc;
```

The problem with this code is that it returns all of the worker id's instead of only the ones in the subquery list. Any explanation would be helpful.

Comment: in the subquery you are referring to b.worker_id which is a table alias from the outer query you probably want to change it to just worker_id.

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output

Comment: Thank you Ian! That solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to check without sample data, but how about this?

```
select worker_name
, b.worker_id

from workers as a
  inner join project_worker as b on a.worker_id=b.worker_id

where b.worker_id in
(
  select pw.worker_id
  from project_worker pw
  group by pw.worker_id
  having count(distinct pw.project_id) > 1
)

order by birthdate desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `cte` to get the works who have joined multiple projects, and then query the `cte` to get the youngest worker:

```
with m_projects as (
   select w.* from workers w where (select sum(p.worker_id = w.worker_id) from project_workers) > 1;
)
select m.worker_name from m_projects m where m.birthdate = (select min(m1.birthdate) from m_projects m1);
```